# How to generate chart and save as Jpeg by using Gwt visualization API

Tags: gwt, gwt-visualization

GWT,Java framework. I wanted to generate chart and save it as jpeg file for sending report's graph to user's email.

I am using GWT visualization api to generate chart for fron-end view. But I wanted to generate chart and save it as jpg in server side.

can any one help me that How to save file as jpeg in server side by using GWT visualization api?

Answer (score 0):

I know [a script](http://www.battlehorse.net/page/topics/charts/save_google_charts_as_image.html) which can export SVG chart to other format. Do you users' browsers support SVG ?

Comment: Hi i want to generate image at server side (java). I have created job scheduling to send email with attached graph image.So that I want to creat chart image from server side by using java.
 Do you know how to generate and export by using java+GWT

Comment: Well, your graph is on the client-side, isn'it ? In your user's browser. You can't access it from your server. You can access the chart data (assuming it comes from some database) but not the java-GWT-translated-to-javascript code. The best you could do is use the above script to generate the image on the client-side and then upload it from the client to some servlet using GWT's RequestBuilder.